# htaccess Rewrite Rule to change domain with respect to request

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect all my request like 
http://baielekkerapp.com/api/recipes?a=34535&b=4353445

to 
http://webservice.baielekkerapp.com/api/recipes?a=34535&b=4353445

I try to write RewriteCond and RewriteRule in htaccess but its not redirecting
please advice thanks

Comment: In what cases should this redirect happen and in what cases should that not happen? With these two url's I can give you an answer that simply redirects all requests to `baielekkerapp.com` to `webservice.bailekkerapp.com`, but I don't think that is what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I come up with this solution

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://webservice.baielekkerapp.com/$1 [L,R]
```

It redirect all request that include /api/

Thanks any way

Answer (score 1):

Try：

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^baielekkerapp.com$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://webservice.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```